# Getting error when initializing a reference

Tags: c++, list, reference

I am trying to declare a reference to a list of ints. When I compile, I am getting a `expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction` error for `list<int>& current;`, where I declare a reference. What is the issue here? I looked all over and this seems to be how a reference is initialized. There must be something I've missed since it won't compile.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    list<int> list;
    list<int>& current;
    current = list; // or just list<int>& current = list; both error
}
```

Comment: reference is another name of object, so all references must be initilized, you cannot simply write: int& r; you should write int d; int& r = d;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how you initialize a reference. Use:

```
list<int>& current = <variable>; // list;
```

`list` is a poor choice of variable name.

1. Using

   ```
   list<int> list;
   ```

   will result in compiler error since you have:

   ```
   using namespace std;
   ```
2. `list` will be terrible variable name even if you hadn't used

   ```
   using namespace std;
   ```

I suggest removing the `using namespace std;` line and using a different name for the variable.

```
std::list<int> my_list;
std::list<int>& current = my_list;
```

Comment: Are you sure this will work with the name `list` redefined as an object?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, No, I don't think it will.

Comment: so when I had `list<int>& current = list;`, it was actually because `list` was not considered the `list<int> ` I just created, but the function? Just trying it now, and it seems if I use a different variable name, it works. That was the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @LeibnizMan, it was both.

Comment: @RSahu "it was both" meaning? the compiler considered it both a function and a variable?

Comment: @LeibnizMan, you need a different variable name AND the reference has to be initialized the way I suggest.